# How to Remove a URL in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console

I need to remove a URL "foo" at `www.example.com/foo`.

But when I type the URL under "Remove URL" and hit continue, on the next page I see the URL changed to

> `http://example.com/www.example.com/foo` (This is not the URL I need to remove.)

***Instead of:***

> `www.example.com/foo`

I have no clue why this is happening. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First,  make sure you're giving the full URL, including `http://`. Although you might think `www.example.com` is a website, it could just as easily be a filename on another website.

Also make sure you are submitting the correct domain for the GWT profile. `http://www.example.com` and `http://example.com` are different sites. If GWT is autocompleting to `http://example.com...` then I would assume you're on the non-www profile. So either submit the non-www URL here, or to to the www profile and submit the www URL there.

Comment: As you rightly pointed out, I have added only `http://example.com` (non-www version) to GWT. `http://www.example.com` (www-version) and `http://example.com` (non-www version) are different sites. But that's the case with every single website on the internet. So does that mean everyone has to add 2 different URL versions to GWT?

Comment: Does that also mean 2 versions of sitemaps have to be generated for both www- and non-www versions of URLs every time, and sitemaps updated at 2 places?

Comment: Just to add to my previous comment, the site has a 301 redirect from the non-www version to the www version.

Comment: @user11221 No, you don't need 2 profiles for a site in GWT. If you are redirecting non-www to www then just make a profile for the www version, and remove the non-www one (since it doesn't really exist as a site). And you don't need sitemaps for both, just make sure your sitemap shows the preferred canonical URLs i.e. the www versions.

Comment: Thanks @DisgruntledGoat. One last question- the site, for a long time, been at the **non-www version**, which means there is quite some data in GWT for this version. (There is ZERO data for the www-version.) In a recent major update to the site, the **www version** has been made the **preferred version** (for no reason). If the non-www version is **deleted from GWT**, would it affect in any way?

Comment: @user11221 you should eventually get the same data in the www profile. But it's not necessary to delete the old profile at all, that's just what I would do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the www version as a separate site to google webmaster tools. Google is treating them as such.